# How to fix this lang.AssertionError?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Whats wrong with my code? It returns Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 
Also, how to check palindrome then?

```
boolean checkPalindrome(String inputString) {

    String [] word;
    word= inputString.split("");
    int len=inputString.length();
    int count=0;

    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(word[i]==word[len-i]){
            count=count+1;
        }

    return count==len;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if string is a palindrome you don't need to check all the string against the other side, only the first half against the second half.

You also have several errors:

`word[len-i]` will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Strings are compared with `equals()`, not `==`.

You have `return` inside the for, it will return the value in the first iteration.

```
boolean checkPalindrome(String inputString) {
    String [] word = inputString.split("");
    int len = inputString.length();
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < len / 2 ; i++) {
        if(word[i].equals(word[len - 1 - i])) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count == len / 2;
}
```